# How to replace parantheses in system() inside a ruby gem

Tags: ruby, regex

I would like to use a system() inside ruby. The string inside system() contents parantheses. So i tried:

```
filenamenew = filename.gsub(/ /, '_').gsub(/(/, '|').gsub(/)/, ']')
```

Sadly i'm getting:

> /home/sascha/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require':
>   /home/sascha/ownCloud/RubymineProjects/youtube_dlhelper/lib/youtube_dlhelper/ripper.rb:57:
>   end pattern with unmatched parenthesis: /(/ (SyntaxError) unmatched
>   close parenthesis: /)/    from
>   /home/sascha/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in`require'  from ./youtube_dlhelper.rb:24:in `'

Can i fix this?

Comment: what's the filename you're getting and what do you want it to look like in the end?  Also you're error and your code don't seem to line up...

Comment: In that case the filename is: Rednex - Cotton Eye Joe (Official Music Video) [HD] - RednexMusic com.m4a

Comment: what do you want it to look like in the end?

Comment: I would like to try out: system("ffmpeg -y -i #{filenamein} -acodec vorbis -vn -ac 2 -aq 60 -strict -2 #{filenamenew}.ogg"). filenamein is the posted string. Filenamin is filenamenew = filename.gsub(/ /, '_'). So the blanks are going away.

Comment: Not exactly answering your question but string has a `shellescape` method that escapes a string so that it is safe to pass to a shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another readable variation could be

```
str = "Rednex - Cotton Eye Joe (Official Music Video) [HD] - RednexMusic com.m4a"

pattern = /[a-zA-Z0-9\-\s\_]/  #=> set the pattern accepted

#=> check each character keep only if they are in the pattern and join them
str.split(//).keep_if{|chr| chr =~ pattern}.join #=> "Rednex - Cotton Eye Joe Official Music Video HD - RednexMusic comm4a"
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because you need to escape the parenthesis in your regex, ie

`"Hello()".gsub(/\(/, ' World')`

will return "Hello World)"

Answer (score 1):

Here's some regex to get rid of parenthesis, brackets and spaces:

```
/(\(|\)|\s|\[|\])/

"Rednex - Cotton Eye Joe (Official Music Video) [HD] - RednexMusic com.m4a".gsub(/(\(|\)|\s|\[|\])/, "")
```

Output:

```
"Rednex-CottonEyeJoeOfficialMusicVideoHD-RednexMusiccom.m4a"
```